# Is it possible to combine Jquery mobile and Objective-C?

Tags: jquery, objective-c

I have been using JQuery mobile for a few days now and one thing I notice that's quite bad with it is that lists are slow, not as responsive as it should be and they tend to be a bit jerky.

So my question is, is it possible to create lists using native code and use JQuery mobile for other areas where it's not so bad at?

Comment: How do you use jQuery mobile? Is this in a webapp (run in the browser), or in an HTML5 "native" app (like Phonegap)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming you are writing a web app, not a native app? The native list in iOS is called `UITableView` and no, you can't use it in a web app.

There are ways to improve responsiveness of animations in a web app, using CSS 3D transitions for example and I am sure it is already taken care of by jQuery mobile. But the performance will never rival that of a native app.

**UPDATE:** The same applies if you are using PhoneGap, since as far as I know, it's just a `UIWebView` inside a native app.

Comment: Well, I am going to use Phonegap to wrap it as an app but I assume what you said still applies then. I think I'll just go back to Sencha Touch though, while it was a lot harder than JQuery mobile, it worked nicer

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you could very well indeed create a native list view, or whatever type of native view you wanted. Just show this view on top of the Phonegap UIWebView. Or perhaps resize the UIWebView and show the UITableView below... Whatever you want to do!

All I'm saying is that, yes, you can create whatever native functionality you want. Nothing is stopping you. There are ways to make Objective-C and Javascript "talk" to each other.

Whether it's a good idea to do that is another question :)

Parts of my Phonegap apps are written in Objective-C, usually because it's impossible to build that part of the app in Javascript. E.g. email functionality.

And if you look at the Phonegap plugins list, there's heaps of plugins that add bits of native functionality to a Phonegap app.

https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iOS

But having said all of that, personally I don't think it's a good idea though to create the list view as a native control.  The point of Phonegap is to not be writing much Objective-C :)

jQuery Mobile can be tweaked to make it faster. Or don't use jQuery Mobile for that list view - you can always write that part in custom HTML+javascript, then add your own CSS touch scroll stuff...